# high memory usage of the `find` command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, memory, find

When running a `find` command on a very large directory I discover that `find`'s use of memory spikes much more than I think it would. I've found it very hard to search for solutions due to the overloaded use of the word "find" ;) This is the command:

`find /var/dir -size +500k -iname "pattern_*" -mtime +90 -type f -exec rm {} \; -print`

Does find keep the entire file list for a directory in memory as it processes it? It seems like it could just examine one entry and move on.  The directory I'm dealing with has ~2 million files in it and I'm starting to run into memory limit issues now.

Are they any ways to use `find` that'll reduce its memory usage?  Any alternatives out there that behave better? I just need to delete files in this directory that meet a couple critera and then print them.  (My last resort solution is I'll just write my own program to perform what I need by streaming in the results of `ls`...)

Comment: I don't have evidence, but it seems highly unlikely that `find` would waste memory like that. Are you sure `find` is the real cause of the memory spike? Also, I doubt it will make a difference, but instead of `-exec`, it's simpler to use `-delete`, that is, `find ... -delete -print`. Lastly, instead of parsing the result of `ls` which is usually not recommended, this could be done fairly easily with a Perl one-liner.

Comment: Let me give using -delete a try! I could go the perl oneliner route, but will have to make sure I process the file list in a stream.